# Chrome compiled code - memory leak

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iframe, memory-leaks

I`m trying to find a memory leak in several browsers.

The actual theory is that this memory leaks are in combination with iFrames in our application. We use these to achieve a application like tab-browsing in our webapp.

All browser seem to keep stuff even if the frame is closed and removed.

In IE the private bytes keep growing (around 2/3 of memory is cleared, 1/3 remains after removing the iFrame) but heap stays constant and in Chrome i noticed that the compiled code of (the same) JavaScript-sources is kept.

I already tried setting the iFrames src to 'about:blank' and clear mostly all of the stuff loaded in the iFrame:

```html
[...]

purgeFrame(this.content[0]);
this.content.remove();

[...]

function purgeFrame (iFrame) {
   $(iFrame.contentWindow.document).unbind();    //remove listeners on document
      $(iFrame.contentWindow.document).find('*').unbind(); //remove listeners on all nodes
      
      $(iFrame).attr('src', 'about:blank');
      
      iFrame.contentWindow.document.innerHTML = '';
      iFrame.contentWindow.document.write('');
      iFrame.contentWindow.close();
      
      $(iFrame).remove();
      
      if(typeof CollectGarbage == "function") {
          CollectGarbage();
      }
}
```

It doesn't change very much.
We are using jQuery v1.12.4 and some other Frameworks like DHTMLX 5.0.2.

Any suggestions or experience with this kind of problem?

[Memory Leak in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiKmD.png)